# Could not execute method of the activity. Calling a Fragment's method from a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm getting the error "Could not execute method of the activity" when trying to call a fragments method.

This method is in a class that extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity. You can see the call to the NasaDailyFragment.onRefresh() on the last line. The NasaDailyImage class extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment. I also tried putting everything on onRefreshClicked() in a thread and then running the thread but got another strange error that I can replicate if that would help.

```
 public class NasaAppActivity extends FragmentActivity {
//stuff
 public void onRefreshClicked(View view){
       Log.d("debug", "in run");
       FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
       NasaDailyImage NasaDailyFragment;
       NasaDailyFragment=(NasaDailyImage)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_iotd);
       Log.d("debug", "fragment has been casted");
       NasaDailyFragment.onRefresh();
}
   }
```

Here's the method that is called

```
public class NasaDailyImage extends Fragment {
//other methods
     public void onRefresh(){
            System.out.println("in onRefresh");
            new RssParseSync(getActivity()).execute(title,description,date,link);//using a class that extends asynctask
        }
}
```

logcat log

```
07-19 03:58:10.906: I/dalvikvm(629): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-19 03:58:10.986: I/dalvikvm(629): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-19 03:58:11.156: D/gralloc_goldfish(629): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-19 03:59:06.446: D/debug(629): in run
07-19 03:59:06.446: D/debug(629): fragment has been casted
07-19 03:59:06.446: D/AndroidRuntime(629): Shutting down VM
07-19 03:59:06.446: W/dalvikvm(629): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  ... 11 more
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.wajumbie.nasadailyimage.NasaAppActivity.onRefresh(NasaAppActivity.java:36)
07-19 03:59:06.466: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  ... 14 more
07-19 03:59:07.066: I/dalvikvm(629): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-19 03:59:07.086: I/dalvikvm(629): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` in the `onRefresh` method at line 36. Could you post the code for that method and point the line 36?

Comment: added it, theres only two lines in it, but how do I see line numbers in eclipse?

Comment: Go to Preferences -> General -> Editors -> TextEditors -> Check `Show line numbers`. Anyway, it line 36 from `NasaAppActivity` is `new RssParseSync(getActivity()).execute...` I don't see what could be null

Comment: Thanks, and likewise...i had everything up and running using all the same method implementations. I'm just trying to use fragments now. I hope someone can figure it out...think I should post the whole RssParseSync class?

Comment: Or maybe the whole class that extends fragment?

Comment: Just for curiosity, can you check to see if either `getActivity()` or the others parameters that you pass to the `RssParseSync`(title,description,date,link) is `null`?

Comment: You know whats weird is that the System.out.println("in onRefresh"); never even gets printed

Comment: I think your only option is to debug the app, step by step and see what exactly is `null` and work from that.

Comment: todo: learn how to use debugger. Thanks for the help!